# Intervention Image cache with Laravel: works once, then "Image cannot be displayed as it contains errors"

Tags: php, image-processing, laravel-4, image-caching

As per the question title, I am using the Intervention package with Laravel. I have the following code in my routes file:

```
Route::get('resize-image/{pathkey}/{filename}/{w?}/{h?}', function($pathkey, $filename, $w=100, $h=100){

    $cacheimage = Image::cache(function($image) use($pathkey, $filename, $w, $h){

        switch($pathkey){
            case 'tour-images':
                $filepath = 'upload/tour-images/' . $filename;
                break;
        }
        return $image->make($filepath)->resize($w,$h);

    },10,true); // cache for 10 minutes

    return Response::make($cacheimage, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'));
});
```

When I call an image using something like: `/resize-image/tour-images/139326085726.jpg/1100/400` it works nicely, then as soon as I reload the page, I get the error:

*The image xxxx cannot be displayed beacause it contains errors*

If I change the dimensions (so forcing it to resize the image again), it works, then.. same problem. When I reload the page, it should be the cached image that is loading this time... but it's not working. What is happening?

Comment: What's your cache driver?

Comment: It's set to 'file' in config/cache.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, now it's working. If I remove 'true' then it works, ie. change this line of code:

```
},10,true); // cache for 10 minutes
```

to:

```
},10); // cache for 10 minutes
```

Not sure why though... I can't find any info that tells me what the 'true' is referring to (I copied this code from a video with little in the way of explanation). If anyone knows what this means, please leave a comment.

Comment: What led you to remove it?

Comment: http://image.intervention.io/api/cache: `returnObj` - Decide if you want the method to return an Intervention Image instance or (by default) the image stream.